# How do i preview a TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, preview

Good day,

I am trying to add a textview preview to my app. For example, i created a news app with card view and I want to have a few lines on the first screen and then it expands the full story in a new activity onclick.

I have already set up the new activity part but I just need the preview on the first screen

Comment: You can use onClick or onClickListener which changes text on clicking it. Search for changing text on clicking it@Shane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have all the News data available on your first `Activity` - `NewsActivity`. 
In that case you just

1. Limit number of lines of preview `TextView` with attribute `android:maxLines="3"`
2. Then on click on `TextView` you would open another activity with an `Intent` and inside the `Intent` pass whole `News object` that corresponds to data displayed in preview `TextView`. Remember that `News object` should be implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` interfaces to be passed with intent.
3. Retrieve data from an `Intent` and display it in the second `Activity` - `NewsDetailsActivity`